# Converting varchar into an int just for the search query?

Tags: php, mysql

What I've been trying to do is to select a row from a table while treating the varchar cells as int ones,

Here's a little explanation:
I have a table of phone numbers, some have "-" in them, some don't.

I wanted to select a number from the database, without including those "-" in the query.
So I used this preg_replace function:

```
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$number); //that leaves only the numbers in the variable
```

and then I run the following query:

```
"SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `phone` = '{$number}'"
```

Now, of course it won't match sometimes since the number Im searching may have "-" in the database, so I tried to look for a solution,
on solution is just converting the cells into int's, but I'm not interested in doing that,

So after looking around, I found a MySQL function named CAST, used like : CAST(phone AS UNSIGNED)

I tried to mess with it, but it didn't seem to work.

Edit:

I kept looking around for a solution, and eventually used MySQL's REPLACE function for that.

```
"SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE REPLACE(phone,'-','') = '{$number}'"
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Why are you storing _formatted_ phone numbers?

Comment: You may find this enlightening: [How do you extract a numerical value from a string in a MySQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

1.
The easiest way to do it might be by using the `REPLACE` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(`phone`, '-', ''), ' ', '') = '5550100';
```

What it does is simpy replacing all whitespaces and dashes with nothing, namely removing all spaces and dashes.

2.
Another alternative to solve the problem would be to use `LIKE`. If the phone numbers with a dash always are formatted the same way like 555-0100 and 555-0199 you can simple insert a %-sign instead of the dash. If your number may be formatted in different ways you can insert a %-between every character. It's not a beautiful solution but it does the trick.

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `phone` LIKE '555%0100';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `phone` LIKE '5%5%5%0%1%0%0';
```

3.
You can use regular expressions. Since MySQL doesn't implement regex replace functions you need to use user defined functions. Have a look at https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp. It supports REGEXP_LIKE, REGEXP_SUBSTR, REGEXP_INSTR and REGEXP_REPLACE.

Edit: Removed my first answer and added some other alternatives.

Comment: I've seen that page today already, tried to mess with it but didn't seem to fit, if it does, could you please show me how to use that in a query like I provided? thank you.

Comment: @Donny: Show us what you actually did.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn’t support extraction of regex matches.

You could try writing a stored function to handle it, but your best bet is to convert the data to ints so that all the numbers are **uniform**. I know you said you don't *want* to do that, but if you *can*, then it’s the **best thing to do**. Otherwise, you could do something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `phone` = '{$number}' OR `phone` = '{$number_with_dashes}'"
```

That is, search for the plain number `OR` the number with dashes.

Answer (score 0):

I kept looking around for a solution, and eventually used MySQL's REPLACE function for that.

```
"SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE REPLACE(phone,'-','') = '{$number}'"
```