# How to group rows by the numeric characters in a string field?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, regex

I have some very ugly data I am trying to massage. It consist of SKUs and I want to group them into product line. E.g.:

```
PRODUCT_ID
----------
313L30WHITE
313L40WHITE
313L30BLACK
3333
2L10RED
2L20BLACK
32341/30/BLK
```

Basically, I want to group items by the first numeric characters in the `PRODUCT_ID` field. I.e., all the characters up to the first non-numeric character. E.g.:

```
PRODUCT_ID    GROUP
----------    -----
313L30WHITE   313
313L40WHITE   313
313L30BLACK   313
3333          3333
2L10RED       2
2L20BLACK     2
32341/30/BLK  32341
```

Seems like a SQL solution would not be elegant. Because of that, I would prefer a Python solution that creates a new table with a new `GROUP` column.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: solving this in mysql is rather unclean in my opinion. but a question regarding the more general issue of extracting numbers from strings in a mysql query was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: After looking at that answer, I agree that the SQL solution would not be elegant. Modified question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that `PRODUCT_ID` will always *start* with one or more numeric characters, then you can just convert it to a number by adding `0`:

```
select PRODUCT_ID,
       0 + PRODUCT_ID as GROUP
  from ...
```

See [§11.2 "Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation" in the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html).

If you want `GROUP` to be textual rather than numeric, then you can write:

```
select PRODUCT_ID,
       concat(0 + PRODUCT_ID) as GROUP
  from ...
```

Comment: Hermes: *"Sweet type coercion of Jupiter!"* +1 for completely unintuitive but efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

this is a perfect place for regex...

```
import re
RE=re.compile(r'\d+')
#Set up the list of SKU's
...
List_of_SKUs.sort(key=lambda x:int(RE.match(x).group()))
```

Now your list is sorted.

The regex just pulls off the longest integer at the start of the string.  The `lambda` function just accesses that portion of the string and casts it to an integer which is used for sorting.

**EDIT**

From there, if you want to print the table, you could do something like:

```
for item in List_of_SKUs:
    print "%s\t%s"%(item,RE.match(item).group())
```

Although there is probably a more efficient way of doing this.