# Two digit Year in YYYY year

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to convert a two digit year into a four digit year. I am trying to get YYYY from something like following. Kindly let me know how can i get it via mysql?

```
SELECT Date_Format(substr("FALL94", 5), "%Y") // OUTPUT NULL 
SELECT YEAR(substr("FALL94", 5)) // OUTPUT NULL
SELECT substr("FALL94", 5) // OUTPUT 94
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility might be `makedate`:

```
select year(makedate(substr('FALL94',5),1));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query FOUND IT HERE, Thanks

Comment: @softgenic:  I did a quick search and found that exact same post.  It seems promising.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
     SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(substr("FALL94", 5), '%y'), '%Y') AS LONG_YEAR;
```

Here `STR_TO_DATE` with `%y` converts the 2 digit string into date and `DATE_FORMAT` with `%Y` converts date back into 4 digit year.

Answer (score 0):

What about [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)?

```
SELECT CONCAT('19', substr("FALL94", 5)) AS `year`
```

will give you `1994`.