# Replacing text in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a column in my table, lets call it thecolumn. The values in that column are either a number, like *100036077*, or a number followed by a name, like that *35921 John Doe*.

I want to replace the names with nothing and add 1000 to the 5 numbers in front of that name (35921 John Doe --> 100035921) in my select. How can I do that without using any additional libraries? There is no native regex replace for MySQL, right?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query take a look at this question, a complex function could be your solution. Though you'll be better off doing it from PHP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit easy... or am I missing something?

```
SELECT CONCAT('1000',SUBSTRING_INDEX('35921 John Doe',' ',1))x;
+-----------+
| x         |
+-----------+
| 100035921 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: There is not always a name in each row. Sometimes, its the correct number already (leading 1000). So I guess I have to differ between the 2 cases (no need to chane a thing or add leading 1000).

Comment: That helped me solving it, thanks! I just added a case/when to differ the 2 cases.

Answer (score 2):

The strategy here is to:

1. Get the substring from the beginning of the string up to the first space (which is the limit between the numeric part and the textual part)
2. Add the string "1000" to the string resulting of 1.
3. Replace current value with the string resulting from 2.

```sql
UPDATE thetable SET thecolumn =
    CONCAT('1000', SUBSTRING_INDEX(thecolumn, ' ', 1));
```