# Mysql - extract number from string

Tags: php, mysql

I have path field in mysql table which stors the path of the page.

It is having page id at the end like 33, 31, 121 ...

How can I write a query to get only the ids?

```
Path
-----
trending-architectures/architecture_detail_page/31
trending-architectures/architecture_detail_page/33
trending-architectures/architecture_detail_page/33
trending-architectures/architecture_detail_page/33
trending-architectures/architecture_detail_page/33
```

Comment: In PHP you can do it using `preg_match_all`
------------------------

`preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);`

or else you can even use 
`preg_match_all("/[^0-9]/","",$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);`

Comment: I have to do this in SELECT statement of mysql.

Comment: All the strings are of same pattern ? i.e. 2 `/` and the last value after `/` is a number ?

Comment: i cannot find a single query solution for this..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query

See this link.. It may help you...

Comment: and can i know 1 thing... Using PHP you can do it easily in a single step, right.. Why do you want to use MySQL for this ????

Comment: yes pattern is same. but I cant use php here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern is same, you can use the function `substring_index()`

```
mysql> select substring_index('trending-architectures/architecture_detail_page/31','/',-1) as num;
+-----+
| num |
+-----+
| 31  |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the select statement would go as

```
select
substring_index(path,'/',-1) as number 
from table_name
;
```

Comment: Hii @Abhik Chakraborty... i think he even have three numbers at the end (like 121, 122, ....).. Will this query work in that case ??

Comment: If the pattern is same it will get any number from the end.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions, the first one utilizes explode to split the string into an array using a "/" deliemeter and then it sets the last value of the array (which is the page id) inside a variable

```
$path = explode('/', $path);
$page = end($path);
```

Other solution just replaces whatever text is before the number with nothing

```
$page = str_replace('trending-architectures/architecture_detail_page/', '', $path);
```

Comment: In php I can. 
 
I have to do this in SELECT statement of mysql.