# Is there any way to get value from JSON format through mysql query or function/procedure?

Tags: mysql, json

Is there any way to get value from JSON format which are stored in database field.

I had tried like below but sometimes it return wrong value and it doesn't seems to correct thing to fetch records.
Actually I am trying to addition of all sizes

```
    SELECT 
    substring_index(substr(size,locate('"xs":"',size)+char_length('"xs":"')),'"',1)+
     substring_index(substr(size,locate('"s":"',size)+char_length('"s":"')),'"',1)+ 
    substring_index(substr(size,locate('"m":"',size)+char_length('"m":"')),'"',1)+ 
    substring_index(substr(size,locate('"l":"',size)+char_length('"l":"')),'"',1)+ 
    substring_index(substr(size,locate('"xl":"',size)+char_length('"xl":"')),'"',1)+ 
    substring_index(substr(size,locate('"xxl":"',size)+char_length('"xxl":"')),'"',1)+ substring_index(substr(size,locate('"xxxl":"',size)+char_length('"xxxl":"')),'"',1)+ 
    substring_index(substr(size,locate('"xs\/s":"',size)+char_length('"xs\/s":"')),'"',1)+ substring_index(substr(size,locate('"m\\/l":"',size)+char_length('"m\\/l":"')),'"',1)+ 
substring_index(substr(size,locate('"xl\\\/xxl":"',size)+char_length('"xl\\\/xxl":"')),'"',1) 

    as qty FROM `table_name`
```

I have also taken the reference to catch numeric value from a string from below question of StackOverflow:
[How do you extract a numerical value from a string in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query)

it returns correct value and i can do addition addition of return value,,but for 2 digit number it is not good for me (like if it return 15 so it is 6 for my case)

Comment: i think you will have to fix your query.. sql is not for returning json. but maybe write e.g. a java or c# tool, use hibernate or entityframework and get objects for all datasets. Then you can export all datasets correct as xml or json. :) It's not very difficult and there are many tutorials :)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger: thanks for your reply..can you suggest in above link as mentioned title
"How do you extract a numerical value from a string in a MySQL query?"
There is a operation like below
SET ret= CONCAT(ret,c);
i tried to get addtion like this
SET ret= ret + CONCAT(ret,c);
can you assist me ..is there any way to count two digit no as it works for 1 digit no.