# Select specific numeric value only in string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-like

I need to isolate a numeric value in a string when i pull it from the database, a string would typically look something like "blah.blah_123".

I need to select all fields containing fx. 1 at the end but not 10, 100, 123.

Here is a part of my query:

```
SELECT `table1`.`shipping_code`
FROM `table2`
  INNER JOIN `table1` ON `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`id`
WHERE `table1`.`shipping_code` LIKE '%3%'
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. (You'd most likely need something with regex)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: Is the integer value always at the end?

Comment: @jarlh Yes but the string in front varies.

Comment: @jarlh It works to some extend but it will also select the higher numbers say i have something like this: "blah.blah_1" and "blah.blah_11".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `_` is a `LIKE` wildcard it needs to be escaped:

```
SELECT `table1`.`shipping_code`
FROM `table2`
  INNER JOIN `table1` ON `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`id`
WHERE `table1`.`shipping_code` LIKE '%#_1' escape '#'
```

Perhaps MySQL has a default escape character? My answer is (more or less) ANSI SQL compliant, but it should work with MySQL too.

Answer (score 0):

This ?

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP '1$'

but maybe regexp having performance issues, if your patern is as much easy to isolate, to use the LIKE operator as suggested by jarlh. Perhaps if this works for you is better to exclude the " _ " from the pattern to match...

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE %1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('abcde_1001001', '[[:digit:]]+1$|[^10|100|123]$')
  FROM DUAL;