# HOW to optimize this mysql query (max,replace,left join)?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I know everyone hates too specify questions, but i need your help.
So - thats the code. It must get info for user

```
 select
 c.id,
 c.firstName,
 c.lastName,
 ...
 dt.code as docCode,
 dt.name as docName,
 replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(cc.contact, ' ',''), '(',''), ')', ''), '-', ''), '+', '') as homePhone,
 replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(cc1.contact, ' ',''), '(',''), ')', ''), '-', ''), '+', '') as cellPhone
      from Client c
        left join ClientPolicy p on p.id=(select max(pp.id) 
                                            from ClientPolicy pp 
                                            where 
                                            pp.client_id = c.id 
                                            and pp.deleted = 0)
        left join rbPolicyType pt on pt.id = p.policyType_id
        left join ClientDocument d on d.id =(SELECT MAX(dd.id) 
                                            FROM ClientDocument dd 
                                            WHERE 
                                            dd.client_id = c.id 
                                            and dd.deleted = 0)
        left join rbDocumentType dt on dt.id = d.documentType_id and dt.code IN ('1')
        left join ClientContact cc ON cc.id = (select MAX(ccc.id) 
                                                FROM ClientContact ccc 
                                                where 
                                                ccc.client_id = c.id 
                                                and ccc.deleted = 0 
                                                and ccc.contactType_id = 1)
        left join ClientContact cc1 ON cc1.id = (SELECT MAX(ccc1.id) 
                                                FROM ClientContact ccc1 
                                                WHERE  
                                                ccc1.client_id = c.id 
                                                and ccc1.deleted = 0 
                                                and ccc1.contactType_id = 3)
  where
 c.deleted = 0
 and c.firstName like '%'
 and c.patrName like '%'
 and c.lastName like '%'
 and replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(cc.contact, ' ',''), '(',''), ')', ''), '-', ''), '+', '') like '%521%'
 and replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(cc1.contact, ' ',''), '(',''), ')', ''), '-', ''), '+', '') like '%8905%'
```

Every % means that user will inserts some data there, for example `like '%8905%`

About `INDEX`'s
I added indexes like below, so this way, I'm sure will not help

```
  INDEX client_insurer (client_id, insurer_id),      
  INDEX policyType_id (policyType_id),
  INDEX Serial_Num (serial, number),
```

About `replace(replace...`
I am sure that regexp will give me just 1 second less and adding this
[How do you extract a numerical value from a string in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query) 

solvation doesn't reduse time(actually added 5 sec more)

I have no idea(mb paste conditions from `where` to `join`?) how make it faster. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't add an `explain`, no information about your data, no table-structure, no information about (useful) indexes. Without this, optimization is just an educated guess.

But I'll try anyway.

I'd try a series of subqueries, since you have to go through all of your data anyway because of the likes.

```
select
 c.id,
 c.firstName,
 c.lastName,
 ...
 dt.code as docCode,
 dt.name as docName,
 cphone1 as as homePhone,
 cphone3 as cellPhone
from

( select *,
  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(cc.contact, ' ',''), '(',''), ')', ''), '-', ''), '+', '') as cphone1,
  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(cc1.contact, ' ',''), '(',''), ')', ''), '-', ''), '+', '') as cphone3
  from 
  (select c.id,
    (select max(pp.id) from ClientPolicy pp 
     where pp.client_id = c.id and pp.deleted = 0) as pmax,
    (select max(dd.id) FROM ClientDocument dd 
     WHERE dd.client_id = c.id and dd.deleted = 0) as dmax,
    (select MAX(ccc.id) FROM ClientContact ccc 
     where ccc.client_id = c.id and ccc.deleted = 0 
     and ccc.contactType_id = 1) as cmax1,
    (SELECT MAX(ccc1.id) FROM ClientContact ccc1 
     WHERE ccc1.client_id = c.id and ccc1.deleted = 0 
     and ccc1.contactType_id = 3) as cmax3
    from Client c        
    where c.deleted = 0
     and c.firstName like '%'
     and c.patrName like '%'
     and c.lastName like '%'
  ) as clientbase
  join ClientContact cc on cc.id = clientbase.cmax1
  join ClientContact cc1 on cc1.id = clientbase.cmax3
) as clientnamed
join client c on c.id = clientnamed.id
left join ClientPolicy p on p.id=clientnamed.pmax
left join rbPolicyType pt on pt.id = p.policyType_id
left join ClientDocument d on d.id = clientnamed.dmax
left join rbDocumentType dt on dt.id = d.documentType_id and dt.code = 1
where cphone1 like '%521%' and cphone3 like '%8905%';
```

If your search parameters '%521%' or '%8905%' are optional (e.g. not always given), you have to use `left join ClientContact cc` (same for cc1), but then do not have `cphone1 like '%521%'`in your `where` (same for `cphone3 like '%8905%'`), as it would act as a `join` again. (And your `like '%'` should actually also not be in there.)

You might get an improvement if you would be able to have the phonenumbers in a clean way in a new column (e.g. updated by a trigger).

Now to indexes:

You absolutely have to have `id` as the primary key.

Create indexes for Client (id, deleted), ClientPolicy (id, deleted) and ClientDocument (id, deleted).

You should try an index (id, deleted, contact_type) or (id, contact_type, deleted) on ClientContact - depending on your data: if you have a lot deleted entries, the first one should work better, otherwise the seconds one.

If these indexes would have a measurable effect depends on your data, but since you didn't tell us anything about your data, try it (having a lot of indexes will slow your inserts/updates down, so don't spam indexes; but again, you didn't tell us anything about the data, so you have to try it out yourself.)

For any follow up, you have to add at least the following

- `explain` to see what mysql is actually doing
- `explain` for the subquery `select c.id,  (select max(pp.id) from ClientPolicy pp ...  c.lastName like '%'` without the surrounding code
- time it takes to get the results for the whole code and just the above subquery

Comment: Well, thank you, i read your comment yesterday and had no time to answer. I'll add u all information, u need. Also, my teamleader strongly approved your indexes like (id,deleted). PS Thank you VERY much