# Mysql split string and get only integer value

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, substring

I have trouble to split string and get only numeric value those are in round bracket. I try `substring_index` but can't get success.

**Column**

```
prd_code

HWC-4054 (100 Pcs available)
HWC-7514 (125 pcs available)
HWC-1516 (total 80 pcs available)
HWC-8008 (80pcs available)
```

**Required output**

```
prd_code

100
125
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below solutions using mysql function.

```
select prd_code,digits(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( prd_code , '(', -1 ), ')', 1)) as one from `your table`
```

use below mysql function :

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION digits( str CHAR(32) ) RETURNS CHAR(32)
BEGIN
 DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1;
 DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT '';
 DECLARE c CHAR(1);

 IF str IS NULL
 THEN 
   RETURN "";
 END IF;

 SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str );
 REPEAT
   BEGIN
     SET c = MID( str, i, 1 );
     IF c BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN 
       SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c);
     END IF;
     SET i = i + 1;
   END;
 UNTIL i > len END REPEAT;
 RETURN ret;
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query)

Comment: It is mandatory to use `digits` function ? i just say without function it is not possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Just now I tried to solve your issue please look on it :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('HWC-4054 (100 Pcs available)','(',-1),' ',1)
```

This is only code snippet, you need to check its suitable for your project or not.

Comment: I think now you need to write stored procedure to achieve your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PATINDEX`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Your_FieldName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Your_FieldName), LEN(Your_FieldName))
```

Comment: Thanks. But i get error of `PATINDEX` does't exist.

Comment: Ok. You can use LOCATE() and REGEXP() instead of PATINDEX

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ucase(pcode), '(', 2),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ucase(pcode), '(', 2 -1)) + 1),'(', ' '),'P',1) as prd_code from tbltest;
```

In this tbltest is table name and pcode is column in that table which contains prd_code value

Comment: Thank you ! but i get null fields.