# Query to convert string data to int data to get max of value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I using CAST and CONVERT sintax to convert data like this picture:

[image]

this is my query:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT, kode_walimurid)) as idmaks FROM walimurid
```

The error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT, kode_walimurid)) as idmaks FROM walimurid LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: you could make substring of kode_walimurid and get get rid of WM string, if it´s always the same pattern

Comment: @Qirel where is kode_walimurid a reserved word??

Comment: @MatthiasBurger `INT` is.

Comment: @Qirel he wants to convert the column to int. int is not the columnname

Comment: Yes, but using `INT` like that is a reserved keyword. It's not a column-name, I'm aware - but that's not how you use `CONVERT()` either.

Comment: @Qirel Sure? https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/07/sql-server-convert-text-to-numbers-integer-cast-and-convert/

Comment: i mean can "WM9" changed to "9"?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert There's nothing `INT` in the manual, and he's getting an error *right at `INT`*

Comment: @Qirel hahaha yes you're right. my syntax is mssql - OP has mysql. damn. :D sorry for that

Comment: But you're right about my dupe flag, probably not the most suitable one! Removed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use "silent" conversion, if you like:

```
SELECT MAX(kode_walimurid + 0) as idmaks
FROM walimurid;
```

This implicit conversion does not return an error, but it will always return 0, because the string starts with a non-digit character.

Presumably, though, you actually want the number that starts at position 3:

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(kode_walimurid, 3) + 0) as idmaks
FROM walimurid;
```

Here is an [example](http://rextester.com/LOJ48169) on Rextester.

Comment: the result always "0"

Comment: @ujang7654321ujang7654321 . . . That's why I offered the second option.

Comment: i try the second option.. still 0

Comment: @ujang7654321ujang7654321 . . . If I say position 3 in the text, I should implement the same in the code.

Comment: Should I use CAST or CONVERT? but using it i have still error the same

Comment: WM8, it mean your query (above) true. because it remove 2 character and get "8"

Comment: Ah i see,, Thank you very much @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

Try with `CAST()` mysql function check here [function_cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)
Like

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(kode_walimurid AS UNSIGNED)) as idmaks FROM walimurid
```

Edit:-
Try to use user define function check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query)

Comment: result "0", i dont know why

Comment: Check the user define function on the above link.