# Get data from strings with format using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get the data numbers from the string in this format using Mysql:

```
A-10001(b)
```

Which means the output should be something like:

```
10001
```

I would like to know whether there is a way which is better than using SUBSTRING. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your current query with us?

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query) can help you... you should add a MySQL function for that. Let me know if it helps you!!!

Comment: This probably won't help with your current problem but with mysql version 8.0  you'll be able to use  REGEXP_SUBSTR  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr

Comment: @Alvaro Niño: It helps!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome, remember to vote up if it helps you @AlvinLau

Comment: I want to do that but I can't. It seems I don't have enough reputation. I am so sorry. I'll vote you up later. @Alvaro Niño

Comment: @AlvinLau nice, don't worry... It was considering you forgot it. Althoug I think I'll put it as an answer and you can select it as valid... Good luck

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way which is better than using SUBSTRING [to pull `10001` from `A-10001(b)` ?

No. Not in a MySQL query.  Whatever you do will almost certainly end up involving `SUBSTRING()`.

A wise programmer might choose to do this in a host language, like php or Java.