# Removing all letters from SQL column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to update a database that was imported incorrectly. There were not supposed to be any letters in a specific column and for some reason, the import tool did not flag it. So I need to find a way to keep all the digits in the column but just remove the Letters Example { abc123def needs to just be 123]

Thank you,

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/978147/9664339

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you extract a numerical value from a string in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query)

Comment: p.s mine comment contains the same link as @ChrisH 's comment but mine comment is generated automatic because i marked (vote closed) this question as a duplicate,

Comment: and what if the data is abc123def123 would you want 123123?  so regardless of text separation keep all numbers in the same sequence?