# return only 1-10000 number from a string using googleSQL

Tags: sql, cloud, google-cloud-sql

Here is the scenario

Table A, Column Elem1

```
Elem1
John1235
kkajdak587
klajdsfds5
sjdfsj35
sdkfjsdj57
skjlfjd1
sdjflsj34
lfkjgk108
ksdjlkdjfk288
ksjsfsj1688
```

I want to extract from the string values of Column Elem 1 only the numbers.
The numbers are from 1 to 10000.

How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you extract a numerical value from a string in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery supports [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_replace) to replace anything that is **not** [0-9]; this will extract all the numbers for you.

```sql
SELECT 
  Elem1, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(Elem1, "[^0-9]", "") as numbersOnly
FROM myTable
```

If you want to then filter this down to values that are between 1-10000, you'll need to put this into the WHERE clause.

```sql
SELECT 
   Elem1,
   cast(REGEXP_REPLACE(Elem1, "[^0-9]", "") as int64) as numbersOnly
FROM myBaseTable 
WHERE cast(REGEXP_REPLACE(Elem1, "[^0-9]", "") as int64) BETWEEN 1 and 10000
```