# MySQL Regexp Solution for Multi-Like Query

Tags: mysql, regex, query-builder, regexp-like

I'm hoping the following will make sense. My query is supposed to return all rows where the string value (+ or - 5) from the `size` column is not present inside its corresponding `title` column.

Table:

```
 --------------
| size  | title|
 --------------
| 50    | 50ml |
| 75    | 75ml |
| 75    | 50ml |
| 100   | 97ml |
 --------------
```

Controller:

```
    $data = [
        'find_all_sizes' => $model
            ->where('CONCAT(brand, " ", title) NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", size - 5, "%")')
            ->where('CONCAT(brand, " ", title) NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", size - 4, "%")')
            ->where('CONCAT(brand, " ", title) NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", size - 3, "%")')
            ->where('CONCAT(brand, " ", title) NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", size - 2, "%")')
            ->where('CONCAT(brand, " ", title) NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", size - 1, "%")')
            ->where('CONCAT(brand, " ", title) NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", size, "%")')
            ->where('CONCAT(brand, " ", title) NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", size + 1, "%")')
            ->where('CONCAT(brand, " ", title) NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", size + 2, "%")')
            ->where('CONCAT(brand, " ", title) NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", size + 3, "%")')
            ->where('CONCAT(brand, " ", title) NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", size + 4, "%")')
            ->where('CONCAT(brand, " ", title) NOT LIKE CONCAT("%", size + 5, "%")')
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->findAll()
    ];
```

This works fine - but I'm guessing there's probably a better way of doing it by using a regular expression, which is where I really need the help.

Comment: Does the `title` always end in exactly "ml"?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Is `size` an integer column?

Comment: @seixwebdev did you find any of the answers below acceptable? If so, you can accept an answer and put closure to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$data = [
        'find_all_sizes' => $model
            ->where("abs(size - cast(replace(title, 'ml', '') as signed)) < 5")
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->findAll()
    ];
```

In SQL, a select * query will look like this assuming `ml` is the only text in title that isn't numeric:

```
select * from t
where abs(size - cast(replace(title, 'ml', '') as signed)) < 5;

+------+-------+
| size | title |
+------+-------+
|   50 | 50ml  |
|   75 | 75ml  |
|  100 | 97ml  |
+------+-------+
```

If your title can contain other strings too, you could create a function like specified here: [How do you extract a numerical value from a string in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978147/how-do-you-extract-a-numerical-value-from-a-string-in-a-mysql-query) and then run

```
select * from t
where abs(size - cast(digits(title) as signed)) < 5;
```

You might get away with just doing

```
select * from t
where abs(size - cast(title as signed)) < 5;
```

or

```
$data = [
        'find_all_sizes' => $model
            ->where("abs(size - cast(title as signed)) < 5")
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->findAll()
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short answer, but it is somewhat kludgy:

```
WHERE 0+title BETWEEN size-5 AND size+5
```

In MySQL, when a string is used in a numeric context, the leading digits are used and the rest is ignored.  (A string with no leading digit(s) is treated as zero.)

(Sorry, no REGEXP needed.)